# SQL Server stored procedure: asking for a parameter when running it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SigleEnseigne
    @Sigle VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT ,
    @Enseigne VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT ,
    @SigleEnseigne1 VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
        @Sigle = ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle, '') ,
        @Enseigne = ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '') ,
        @SigleEnseigne1 = CASE 
                             WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%'
                                THEN '      / ' + ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '')
                             WHEN ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle, '') = ''
                                  AND ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '') = ''
                                THEN ''
                             ELSE @Sigle + ' / ' + @Enseigne
                          END
    FROM    
        John_Jack
END
GO
```

I've been able to create it, thanks to help here, in SO.

However when I'm executing the stored procedure, I get the following error

> Msg 201, Niveau 16, État 4, Procédure SigleEnseigne, Ligne 89
>   La procédure ou fonction 'SigleEnseigne' attend le paramètre '**@Sigle**', qui n'a pas été fourni.

It is asking me for a parameter `@Sigle`, yet it has everything needed inside my stored procedure.

Update : I'm executing the code like this

```
EXEC SigleEnseigne
```

Can anyone enlighten me, please?

Thanks

Comment: can you paste the code where you're actually executing the stored procedure?

Comment: Hi @Dane: See my update

Comment: Ah... Maybe you need to default the variables to nothing ("") as if you do an isnull on a record that doesn't EXIST then it's null.

Comment: @AndyK, I answered your previous question and you seem to use my query but didn't accept the answer. And I have answered you on this question in the comment. Why did you ask a new question?

Comment: True @GiorgiNakeuri. Thanks. Many questions are hovering , this is the why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the procedure you use all parameter as output, then you should to set these parameters when you call the proc

```
declare 
@Sigle VARCHAR(150), @Enseigne VARCHAR(150), @SigleEnseigne1 VARCHAR(150)
EXEC  SigleEnseigne @Sigle OUTPUT, @Enseigne OUTPUT, @SigleEnseigne1 OUTPUT
```

Comment: Yes this simply is this case here. However my comment still stands in the fact that you need to check if the record exists to isnull it. Otherwise you're just going to get null.

Comment: Hi @MegaTron, thanks. Is there a way to set the variable inside of a sp and not to mention it as an input or an output, please?

Comment: Of course, just put the `declare @Sigle VARCHAR(150), ...` after `BEGIN ` and in the end of procedure add `select @Sigle, @Enseigne, @SigleEnseigne1`. It will return value of variables as select query

Comment: Yes, just add `declare` keyword before declaring variables

Comment: Glad to have been of help